# Why am I getting a "Search for app in the Store" dialog?

Tags: c#, wpf

When a co-worker runs an exe I built they a "Search for app in the Store" dialog. Doesnt happen when I run the exe. Anybody else run into this? This exe is built on the .NET Framework 4.8 and uses WPF for the GUI.

[image]

Comment: What version of Windows does your co-worker have? See <https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies>.

Comment: Is the app installed or do you just click on the exe?

Comment: I'm running Win 10 Enterprise 21H1 (OS Build 19043.1110). He's running Win 10 Enterprise 1803 (OS Build 17134.2208)

Answer (score 0):

This suggestion probably requires Windows local admin.
If you right mouse click on the exe and select Properties, at the bottom of the General tab there may be the message, "This file came from another computer and might be blocked to help protect this computer". Next to this is an "Unblock" check box. Tick the box and click Apply.

Answer (score -1):

Per your comments on the question, your coworker is running Windows 10, version 1803.

If you consult the [.NET Framework versions and dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies#net-framework-48) documentation, you will notice that under .NET Framework 4.8, the Windows versions list has *10 April 2018 Update (Version 1803)* listed with a ➕, indicating that the framework is not installed by default on that OS.

Have your coworker install the .NET Framework 4.8 runtime. They can get it from [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download).